# How to mock constructor of subclass in Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, constructor, jmockit

Classes structures look likes below:

```
class A {
 protected String a;
 protected String b;

 A(String b1) {
    new A("A111", b1);
 }

 A(String a1, String b1) {
   a = a1;
   b = b1;
 }
}

class B extends A {

  B(String b) {
    super("A", b);
  }
}
```

I need to write JUnit test case and needs to mock constructor for class A so that whenever object for class B needs to create then mock constructor for class A should get invoke and returns object from mock constructor.

I tried following :

```
       new MockUp<A>() {

            @Mock
            public void $init(String b1) {
                new A("A11111111", b1);
            }
        };
```

But object created in mocked constructor hasn't been returned.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Could you explain a bit more what you want to do and what you want to test?

Comment: It seems like you want to separate the superclass constructor from the subclass, and only test the logic of the subclass (by mocking the superclass)? But here's the thing: constructors don't really return objects - when you call `super()` you don't assign it to anything, because it's operating on `this`... So you can`t "invoke and return object from mock constructor" in this case.

Comment: I want to mock single parameterized constructor and from mock constructor, I want to create object using two parametrized constructor and return same object for further use.

Comment: @dcsohl Yes.. you got it right... any how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you were on the right path ... it takes a combination of `@Mock`, `MockUp`, `Invocation` and `Deencapsulation` ... You have to add an `Invocation` to your `$init` mock method, and then use Deencapsulation to poke around at `A` internals. Here's an example. I used your A and B classes, only cleaning them up a little bit and adding getters for ease-of-use. I deliberately did not add setters, so I could show off how to get around a lack of setters.

```
package com.example.dcsohl;

import org.junit.Test;

import mockit.Deencapsulation;
import mockit.Invocation;
import mockit.Mock;
import mockit.MockUp;

public class TestTest {

    public static class A {
        protected String a;
        protected String b;

        public A(String b1) {
            this("A111", b1);
        }

        public A(String a1, String b1) {
            a = a1;
            b = b1;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public B(String b1) {
            super("A", b1);
        }

        public String getA() {
            return this.a;
        }

        public String getB(){
            return this.b;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new MockUp<A>() {
            @Mock public void $init(Invocation inv, String a1, String b1) {
                A a = inv.getInvokedInstance();
                Deencapsulation.setField(a, "b", b1);
            }
        };

        B b = new B("foo");

        System.out.println(b.getA());
        System.out.println(b.getB());

    }

}
```

You'll note that, at the end, the printouts show that I successfully set the value of `b` but, having left `a` alone, it comes out as `null`.